# Can I use Xcode 7 lightweight syntax and still support Travis?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode7, travis-ci

I'd like to use Xcode 7.0 lightweight syntax:

```
NSArray<NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *> *fooList;
```

But Travis is only supporting Xcode 6.1: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment/

Is there a way to ignore the angle brackets when building with Xcode 6 for Travis?

[edit: **question is not relevant: [Travis supports Xcode 7](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/objective-c/#Supported-OS-X-iOS-SDK-versions)**]

Comment: I used travis-ci in the past. but due to their lacking abilities to keep their tool chain for mac/ios up-to-date, week long outages, we are going with another solution now: [buildkite](https://buildkite.com). As simple to configure as travis, but executed on our hardware with our setup. A new version of Xcode is released? We just install it. done.

Answer (score 2):

The lightweight generics syntax found in newer versions of Objective-C require a newer version of the compiler not found in Xcode 6.

So there is no simple way to get such syntax to compile while using Xcode 6.

Your only option would be terrible code such as:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 90000
    NSArray *fooList;
#else
    NSArray<NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *> *fooList;
#endif
```

Needless to say that is far from a good idea.

But you have a bigger issue. Trying to use Xcode 6 to do continuous integration builds of an app that you really want to build with Xcode 7 is a bad idea. You end up not building or testing the proper code. You can't even support the proper APIs or version of iOS.

The much better solution is to use a CI tool that supports the latest version of Xcode and related SDKs/APIs.

Comment: @Cœur I'm not familiar with any.